# Summing data for last 7 day look back window

Tags: mysql, sql

I want a query that can give result with sum of last 7 day look back.

I want output date and sum of last 7 day look back impressions for each date

e.g. I have a table tblFactImps with below data:

```
dateFact    impressions id
2015-07-01  4022        30
2015-07-02  4021        33 
2015-07-03  4011        34  
2015-07-04  4029        35
2015-07-05  1023        39
2015-07-06  3023        92
2015-07-07  8027        66
2015-07-08  2024        89
```

I need output with 2 columns:

```
dateFact    impressions_last_7
```

query I got:

```
select  dateFact, sum(if(datediff(curdate(), dateFact)<=7, impressions,0)) impressions_last_7 from  tblFactImps group by  dateFact;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

If your fact table is not too big, then a correlated subquery is a simple way to do what you want:

```
select i.dateFact,
       (select sum(i2.impressions)
        from tblFactImps i2
        where i2.dateFact >= i.dateFact - interval 6 day
       ) as impressions_last_7
from tblFactImps i;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by [`LEFT OUTER JOIN`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-joins)ing the table with itself on a date range, and summing the impressions grouped by date, as follows:

```
SELECT
    t1.dateFact,
    SUM(t2.impressions) AS impressions_last_7
FROM
    tblFactImps t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    tblFactImps t2
ON
    t2.dateFact BETWEEN
        DATE_SUB(t1.dateFact, INTERVAL 6 DAY)
        AND t1.dateFact
GROUP BY
    t1.dateFact;
```

This should give you a sliding 7-day sum for each date in your table.

Assuming your `dateFact` column is indexed, this query should also be relatively fast.